# The uniform measure on $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let A be a finite set and consider $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$. A is equipped with the discrete topology and $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ with the associated product topology.

By $\mu_u$, denote the uniform measure on $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Now my question is: How is $\mu_u$ to be understood i.e. how it is defined?

I guess it is something like *giving same weight to each configuration*, whatever that weight is. But whats the topological support of this measure? Maybe whole $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the support?

**Edit**:

Sorry, now I found in the text linked in the comment what is meant (on p. 4):

Let $[u]_t:=\left\{x\in A^{\mathbb{Z}}: x_t=u_1,\ldots,x_{t+\lvert u\rvert}=u_{\lvert u\rvert}\right\}$, i.e. this is a cylinder set. And then

$$
\mu_u([u]_t)=1/\#A^k
$$

if $u$ is of length $k$.

I know this measure under the notion Bernouilli-measure.

But one questions remain: What is the support of this measure? All cylinder sets?

Comment: Where did you see this referenced?

Comment: I saw this here :http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312136.pdf on page 15 below the formula for $h_{\text{Top}}(F)$.

Comment: The support is $A^{\Bbb Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F\subset\Bbb Z$ is finite then $A^F$ is a finite set, so there is a uniform probability measure $\mu_F$ on $A^F$; that's the measure that assigns the same measure to each point.

And there is a natural projection $\pi_F:A^{\Bbb Z}\to A^F$. The uniform measure $\mu_u$ is defined by $$\mu_u(\pi_F^{-1}(S))=\mu_F(S)\quad(S\subset A^F).$$

---

Asking whether the support is the set of all cylinder sets makes no sense; if $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ then the support of $\mu$ is a subset of $X$, not a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$.

Here the support of $\mu_u$ is $A^{\Bbb Z}$. That follows from the definition of the support of a measure, since if $V\subset A^{\Bbb Z}$ is a nonemmpty open set the definition above shows that $\mu_u(V)>0$.

Comment: I am wondering what might be $F$ here.

Comment: ??? Read again - I said what $F$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what F is in the linked text from where I got the issue.

Comment: Ah, I found it. I'll add it to my answer.